# Websites on server redirected to defaultwebpage.cgi after AutoSSL change

Tags: ssl, cpanel, lets-encrypt, whm

I had AutoSSL by Comodo on my CentOS WHM VPS previously configured and running. After the certificates got expired, I installed Let's Encrypt and tried to renew certificates via that service which failed with error that signified a DCV validation issue due to me to using the server's DNS. Also the HTTP validation was failing too.

Later, I switched back to Comodo AutoSSL and renewed two of the sites while all others failed with same error above.

Now the issue that persists is that I can't access the websites except one (the main account on WHM). All of the sites are showing `defaultwebpage.cgi`

What might possibly be the issue and what can be done to get the system back up?

Comment: Have you rebuildt the apache virtual hosts?

Comment: Yes @BogdanStoica. I did.

Comment: It's pretty hard to say then without actually being able to see what's going on on the server (that implies checking apache logs, site logs etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the issue solved. The faults on my setup that made the DCV to fail were (different for different domains).

- For a few domains, the DNS had AAA records(with IPV6 values) that prevented the updation.
- For another domain the issue was that the DNS was on cloudflare and it wasn't getting auto updated. So, i had to manually enter the record that has name '_cpanel-dcv-test-record' and a value that had a data like '_cpanel-dcv-test-record=UF0zA7G97dxugw_u10XVpkRJ0faQg2bk2UHf2vDJkhKcElawaQqyaLtCL3VsquAGxv' (sample values for reference. not real)

I made the above changes, selected the domains (Inside CPanel for individual account > SSL > SSL Status) that needed the change and pressed the 'Run Auto SSL'.

Hope this helps someone who goes through a smilar situation.